# biztalk 2010 table looping functoid not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a flat file that I'm trying to transform into X12_00401_820. When I use the table looping and table extractor, the loop never happens.

Below is my map:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/OOy3PJj.png]

Below is the output. The invoice numbers are looping right, but I'm only getting the first amount, not the amount for each invoice.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WmdSAbW.png]

Answer (score 0):

> The first input parameter to this functoid must be a scoping link, and
>   the second represents the number of columns in the data grid.

The first parameter of your functoid is the scope, you have to set your scope to SellersInvoiceNumber **(don't link it graphically just write in input[0] SellersInvoiceNumber )**

The second parameter of your functoid is the number of columns, you have to put 2 there as you will have two columns in your grid

So the third and fourth parameters will be your SellersInvoiceNumber and Invoice amount field (link it graphically as you already did)

Don't forget to configure your columns in the Table Looping Grid but i guess you've already done that

This should work